# Excel VBA- remove part of the string

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to delete part of the string. For example
`mystring="site, site text, sales "`

I want to remove '**site**' from mystring. My required output is **"site text, sales"**

I use this line of code :

```
s1 = Replace(mystring, "site", "")
```

but i am getting `"text, sales"`

I am not sure how to do this and I'd really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
replace("site, site text, sales ","site, ","",1,1)
```

You can also send as a parameter the start position and then the number of times you want to replace... (the default is -1)

Comment: For the record, follows the parameters of replace: `Public Function Replace(
   ByVal Expression As String,
   ByVal Find As String,
   ByVal Replacement As String,
   Optional ByVal Start As Integer = 1,
   Optional ByVal Count As Integer = -1,
   Optional ByVal Compare As CompareMethod = CompareMethod.Binary
) As String`

Answer (score 5):

There are a lot of different options here :

Just by **adding the coma in the search string** to be replaced and use `Trim` to get rid of spaces :

```
s1 = Trim(Replace(mystring, "site,", ""))
```

Specify **the number of time you want the string to be replaced** (first "1" is the start, the second for the number of replacements)

```
s1 = Trim(Replace(mystring, "site,", "",1,1))
```

Or the hard/bad way, to **decompose your string in two pieces** after the first occurence and then recombine to get result...

```
TempStart = Left(mystring, InStr(1, mystring, "site") + Len(mystring) + 1)
TempEnd = Replace(mystring, TempStart, "")
TempStart = Replace(TempStart, "site", "")
mystring = CStr(TempStart & TempEnd)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also user VB's MID function like this:

```
Mystring=Mid(myString, 6)
```

output will be **"site text, sales"**

Just specify the number of characters you want to be removed in the **number** part.

Answer (score 3):

In my case I wanted to remove the part of the strings that was between "[" and "]". And the following code worked great.

So With original string in column A (and solution in column B):

```
Sub remove_in_string()

Dim i, lrowA, remChar As Long
Dim mString As String

lrowA = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lrowA

mString = Cells(i, 1).Value

    If InStr(mString, "[") > 0 Then

        remChar = InStr(mString, "]") - InStr(mString, "[") + 1

        Cells(i, 2).Value = Left(mString, Len(mString) - remChar)

    ElseIf InStr(mString, "[") = 0 Then

        Cells(i, 2).Value = Cells(i, 1).Value

    End If

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Good but better to use InStrRev instead of InStr and Check "]" is the last character or not.